# How to customize a message in msi creation using InstallShied 2009?

Tags: windows, installation

I am creating msi set up for x64 bit and have already declared in Template Summary that it is x64  and 1033 for language setting. I've created a condition as well to give a message '64 bit processor required' if the version is 'NOTVersionNT64'. When I tried to install this set up on 32bit it must give me a message like '64 bit processor required' but instead it is giving me the below message-
'This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor.'

How can I customize the above message to give a user friendly message like '64-bit processor needed to run this set up'?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vidya

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't customize this message.

Windows Installers detects your package is for 64 bit architecture whereas you try to run it at 32 bit message, and displays error message. The same error message is displayed for all 64 bit packages on 32 bit machines.

The only way to customize the message is to use a bootstrapper. I wouldn't recommend using it unless you really need a bootstrapper.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, but we are willing to give user friendly message to the users when they try to run inappropriate set up (64 bit setup on 32- bit machine or 32-bit setup on 64-bit machine) thats why I tried to customize but still it is giving me predefined message. Is there a way to notify/give a warning to users if they are running incorrect setup? Thanks in a bunch for the suggestion.

Comment: You can't customize the message if you distribute .msi file. The only to customize the message is to use (or write) a bootsrapper application which will contain the MSI file. This app checks the architecture of the OS and either shows the error message, or extracts the contained MSI file and launches it. By the way, “64 bit processor required” is neither friendly message, as 64 bit processor can run 32 bit operating system, and it is *64 bit operating system* that you application requires. Of course, this implies 64 bit capable processor.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, is there a way to go with msi installer even if we have UAC feature turned on? I tried to search this but unable to get anything. Also, msi setup doesn't allow users without Admin access to run the installation. Could you please suggest any idea on this one too?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand you question. Windows Installer packages are compatible with UAC and prompt for elevation if necessary. If you want regular users to be able to install your package without elevation, then the package must be prepared as *per-user* rather than *per-machine*. In *per-user* installation, all files and registry entries are written to the current user's profile. Other users of this computer won't see this application is installed. Per-user installations are as common as per-machine, because app files are not protected from modification.

Comment: It is better to create separate questions rather than ask additional unrelated questions in comments: that way other users would benefit from answers to those question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Alexey. I am sorry to put several questions within the same thread, will take of this further.